# Enable / Disable command button primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My page has a search button to bring rates the address entered. 
After the research I want to be held to enable the print button.

```
                <p:commandButton value="#{msg['btn-search']}"
                    styleClass="btn btn-primary" onclick="codeAddress()" />
                <p:remoteCommand actionListener="#{searchBean.addMarker()}"
                    name="consultaValor"
                    update="bandeira1, bandeira2,bandeira1Value, bandeira2Value,origemInfo,addressInfo"/>
                <p:commandButton id="print" value="Imprimir" styleClass="btn btn-primary" rendered="#{searchBean.print.booleanValue()}" >
                    <p:printer target="information" />
                </p:commandButton>
```

I tried to use the rendered attribute that receives a boolean of my searchBean but did not work can anyone help me?

```
private Boolean print = false;

public Boolean getPrint() {
    return print;
}

public void setPrint(Boolean print) {
    this.print = print;
}
public void addMarker() {
    Marker marker = new Marker(new LatLng(lat, lng),address);
    emptyModel.addOverlay(marker);           
    result = true;
    String wktFilter = "POINT("+getLng()+" "+getLat()+")";

    findByWKT(wktFilter);

    print = true;

}
```

The addMarker method is called by the search button then it went true to the boolean print but does not work.

Comment: 1. you don't need `booleanValue()`, 2. `onclick` on a `commandButton` makes for some suprises. 3. So you're saying that `codeAddress` will call `consultaValor`? Are you sure the actionListener and the new render phase get to see the same bean (breakpoint the bean's constructor to find out)?

Comment: Didn't you forget an `update="... print"` on the `p:remoteCommand`?

Comment: Agree with above comments. Besides I think you need to either use "disabled" instead of "rendered" on the button, or wrap the button in i.e. an outputPanel and update this component instead. Problem is that you can't update a component with ajax that is not in the componenttree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your backing bean is basically fine, you just need to modify your front end page.

Just like @mabi, @rion18 and @Jaqen H'ghar said, you should:

1. Remove `booleanValue()`
2. Call `remoteCommand` with a `onclick` of a `commandButton`.
3. Add `update="print"` on the `p:remoteCommand`.
4. Use `disabled` instead of `rendered`.(which I use `display` here.)

So your front end will looks like:

```
<p:commandButton value="btn-search" styleClass="btn btn-primary" />
<p:commandButton value="remote" onclick="consultaValor()"/>
<p:remoteCommand actionListener="#{searchBean.addMarker()}"
                         name="consultaValor" 
                         update="print"/>
<p:commandButton id="print" value="Imprimir" styleClass="btn btn-primary" style="display:#{searchBean.print?'inline':'none'}" >

</p:commandButton>
```

### Please note that

1. **I removed something in your code** because I didn't know what do they mean in your code (like `bandeira1,bandeira2,bandeira1Value,bandeira2Value,origemInfo,addressInfo...`), **you should add them back** if you use the code I post here.
2. I added a `p:commandButton` so that the `p:remoteCommand` is called. **Make sure the remoteCommand is called** if you want to remove the button I added.